# I want a script to show a string that I have declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, events, button

How do I have a javascript popup showing a string? I declared a string:

```
string myString;
myString = "hello world!";

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "message",
        "window.alert('myString');", true);
}
```

But it shows `myString` instead of `hello world!`

Comment: Is `button1` inside an `UpdatePanel`? If that is the case you need to give this method the `updatePanel.GetType()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un oh you are using 'mystring' as a literal instead of using its Text value. Do it like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), 
             "message", 
             "window.alert("\'" + myString + "\'");",
             true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `String.Format`

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "message",
    String.Format("window.alert('{0}');", myString),
    true);
```

`String.Format` will replace parameters `{0}{1}...{n}` for the variable in the index passed, more info on MSDN: [String.Format Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)